# Reserving a part of console using assembly language in X86_32 Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, console, text-editor

I'm developing a text editor like VI with assembly and need to take control of console, exactly like Vi, for example changing the position of cursor and inserting and deleting of strings.
I googled a lot but didn't find any good suggestion, the code is not my problem, I want to get the idea of how to do it, then i could code it myself
I'm using NASM and 32 bit Linux OS.

Comment: How far have you got in your development? How are you addressing the screen at the moment? Are you using standard Linux libraries? If so, how are you loading them?

Comment: My problem in it's process is dynamic interacting with terminal, my program works fine with static usage of terminal, I mean just input and output from terminal. 
Not using libraries so far, it's pure assembly because it's my assembly project

Answer (score 2):

Look into sources of [`curses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library ([`ncurses(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/ncurses/)) and see how Unix terminals are manipulated.

Comment: I checked the links, but the problem is my prof. doesn't allow us to use C libraries, and he wants pure assembly, does it have any solution this way?